# Place markers in map using json input by an excel file

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps-api-3

I have this code and just don't know how to make it work. 
I can upload my excel file succesfully, but don't know how to get the map to read the json result.

I know I should replace this code:

```
    fetch('https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json')
```

But don't know exactly how to link it with the results that this code gives me:

```
  <pre ng-show="excel" id="datos">{{excel | json}}</pre>
```

Here's the full code:

```
     <body ng-app="xlsxApp" ng-controller="xlsxCtrl" onload = "loadMap()">

      <div class="container">
       <h2>Seleccionar archivo Excel:</h2>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" xlsx-model="excel" multiple>
        <pre ng-show="excel" id="datos">{{excel | json}}</pre>
      </div>

    <div id = "map" style = "width:640px; height:480px;"></div>
     <script>

        const getLocations = () => {
         fetch('https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json')
         .then(response => response.json())
         .then(locations => {
          let locationsInfo = []

      locations.forEach(location => {
        let locationData = {
            position: 
     {lat:location.punto.coordinates[1],lng:location.punto.coordinates[0]},
            name:location.nombre_sede                
        }
        locationsInfo.push(locationData)
    })
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((data)=>{
            let currentPosition = {
                lat: data.coords.latitude,
                lng: data.coords.longitude
            }
            dibujarMapa(currentPosition, locationsInfo)
        })
    }
})
}
       const dibujarMapa = (obj, locationsInfo) => {
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    zoom: 4,
    center: obj
})
let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: obj,
    title: 'Tu ubicacion'
})
marker.setMap(map)

let markers = locationsInfo.map(place => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: place.position,
        map: map,
        title: place.name
    })
})
}
 window.addEventListener('load',getLocations)
  </script>

 <script async defer
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the [link: https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json](https://www.datos.gov.co/resource/g373-n3yy.json) the JSON format your are trying to read?  If not, could you provide a sample of what you are getting from excel.

Comment: It's a simple spreadsheet with the columns "Code, User, Adress, lat, lng".
My guess is that even though it has coordinates, is not written in the right format.
In any case, what I need is a way to make the map read the textbox that shows up when I upload an excel file.